# Is there a way to bind parameters to db2 dialect(ibm_db_sa) compiled query after compiling?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, db2

I am trying to compiled query using db2 dialect ibm_db_sa. After compiling, it binds '?' instead of parameter.

I have tried same for MSSQL and Oracle dialects, they are giving expected results.

```
import ibm_db_sa
from sqlalchemy import bindparam
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer

tab = Table('customers', MetaData(), Column('cust_id', Integer, 
primary_key=True))
stmt = select([tab]).where(literal_column('cust_id') == 
bindparam('cust_id'))
ms_sql = stmt.compile(dialect=mssql.dialect())
oracle_q = stmt.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect())
db2 = stmt.compile(dialect=ibm_db_sa.dialect())
```

If i print all 3 queries, will output:

```
MSSQL => SELECT customers.cust_id FROM customers WHERE cust_id = :cust_id
Oracle => SELECT customers.cust_id FROM customers WHERE cust_id = :cust_id
DB2 => SELECT customers.cust_id FROM customers WHERE cust_id = ?
```

Is there any way to get DB2 query same as others ?

Comment: Are you asking about syntax differences in the compiled statements (database dialects) or about how to use it?

Comment: Why does it matter? SQLA is supposed to handle the differences in DB-API implementations regarding parameters: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Comment: Ok after compiling I am trying to execute same. So what parameter i should pass for that '?'
for example, `conn.execute(stmt, {cust_id: 1})`

Comment: You probably have tried the 2-3 possible combinations and figured out something like `conn.execute(stmt,1)` or `conn.execute(stmt,custid)`...?

Comment: @data_henrik for multiple values how should i pass values in execute method. I have tried passing `conn.execute(stmt, (1, 1))` following [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute]  but its giving error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: see below - it is straight from the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute]) that you reference have that solution:

> In the case that a plain SQL string is passed, and the underlying
>   DBAPI accepts positional bind parameters, a collection of tuples or
>   individual values in *multiparams may be passed:

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)",
    (1, "v1"), (2, "v2")
)

conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)",
    1, "v1"
)
```

For Db2, you just pass a comma-separated list of values as documented in the 2nd example:

```
conn.execute(stmt,1, "2nd value", storeID, whatever)
```

Comment: i was using `conn.execute(text(stmt), [1])` causing an issue when not using `text()` it worked !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

From SQLAlchemy v2.0 you can no longer execute a statement as a `str` it must be wrapped in `sqlalchemy.text()`. Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#execute-method-more-strict-execution-options-are-more-prominent

For DB2 here is a working example, tested using the v11.5 docker image, connecting using a `ibm_db_sa://` connection string and named parameters (I haven't been able to get positional `?` parameters to work):

```py
import sqlalchemy
conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(
    "INSERT INTO table (id, value)
    VALUES (:idvalue, :valuevalue)").bindparams(
    idvalue="v1",
    valuevalue="v2",
    )
)
```